# PHP SQL Display images

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've written a php code to display all the images. But there's is something wrong in the code and I can't fix it. It's kind of a syntax error but I've wasted hours over it and still mixing up the "quotes(')"..here's my php code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($display_query)){
    print "<tr><td>".$row['itemid']."</td><td><img src="resources/wh/'.$row['itemid'].'.png"/></td><td>".$row['description']."</td><td>";
    print "&#8377;".$row['cost']."</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: "something wrong " care to tell us what?

Comment: first check with firebug,is image is loading or not?if not try with one image and go for multiple images

Comment: while($row = mysql_fetch_array($display_query)){
                        echo "<tr><td>".$row['itemid']."</td><td>";
                        echo '<img src="resources/wh/'.$row['itemid'].'.png" title="'.$row['itemid'].'"/>';
      echo "</td><td>".$row['description']."</td><td>";
      echo "&#8377;".$row['cost']."</td></tr>";
                    }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"<tr><td>".$row['itemid']."</td><td><img src="resources/wh/'.$row['itemid'].'.png"/></td><td>".$row['description']."</td><td>";
```

Should be

```
"<tr><td>".$row['itemid'] . '</td><td><img src="resources/wh/'.$row['itemid'].'.png"/></td><td>'.$row['description']."</td><td>";
```

But mix `'` and `"` make your code a mess, you could use [HEREDOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#PHP) to make it more readable.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($display_query)){
  echo <<<EOF
<tr>
    <td>{$row['itemid']}</td>
    <td><img src="resources/wh/{$row['itemid']}.png"/></td>
    <td>{$row['description']}</td>
    <td>&#8377;{$row['cost']}</td>
</tr>
EOF;
}
```

Comment: Or, since he's using ", "<tr><td>{$row['itemid']}</td><td><img src='resources/wh/{$row['itemid']}.png'/></td><td>{$row['description']}</td><td>"; but yeah, HEREDOC is tidier. :)

Comment: I would point users to some explanation of HEREDOCs, as it's not something a new programmer will just run into - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#PHP

Answer (score 2):

Your concatenation of string and quotation is not right. Try this -

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($display_query)){
    print "<tr><td>" . $row['itemid']."</td><td><img src=" . 'resources/wh/' .$row['itemid']. ".png'/></td><td>".$row['description'] . "</td><td>";
    print "&#8377;".$row['cost']."</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: Your concatenation of string and quotation is not right - you added an extra single-quote before the file extension, and for some reason separated the path into it's own string

Comment: Oh! it should be after the file extension. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is just make proper pencuation in your code.

The correct code is:

```
print "<tr><td>".$row['itemid']."</td><td><img src='resources/wh/".$row['itemid'].".png'/></td><td>".$row['description']."</td><td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

from db we get column value of rating  $number=$row->rating ;

if we want TO print image as rating value in a table row then 
then

```
 $number=$row->rating   ;   
 $middle="";
 $first="<td width='200' align='left'>";
  for($x=1;$x<=$number;$x++) {

   $middle=$middle.img($fullimage_properties);  
}


if (strpos($number,'.')) {
    $middle=$middle.img($halfimage_properties); 
    $x++;
}
while ($x<=5) {
    $middle=$middle.img($blankimage_properties);    ;
    $x++;
}


echo $last=$first.$middle."</td>";
```